# pjsip android unregister/register crash

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm using pjsip for VOIP calling. In order to preserve battery life the strategy is to unregister and delete sip account whenever a call is finished. And incoming calls are notified by GCM, which will trigger registering of sip account.

This works but is unstable. Sometimes the app crashes down in the pjsip native layer (I'm suspecting because gc kicks in on the wrong thread?).

I carefully call .delete() on all things. But this doesn't help. Sometimes I can do 10-15 calls before a crash. But on other devices alot fewer.

Crashes I get just give me an unhelpful Fatal signal 11:

```
10-27 22:53:23.045    1068-2014/com.funbers.app /System.out﹕ 22:53:23.204   pjsua_core.c  .RX 619 bytes Response msg 200/REGISTER/cseq=24488 (rdata0x613e2540) from TLS 162.209.100.164:5061:
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ SIP/2.0 200 OK
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 85.225.249.21:46425;branch=z9hG4bKPjQ71QoAFam.OlO6FEvuVz2gM5PPu4DWmH;alias;received=85.225.249.21;rport=46425
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ From: "12025999147" <sip:1112220002QQQ140431267693@devastus01.funbers.net>;tag=XvzX1mdof0g94DVFNNaryzYNTCpwFwD0
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ To: "12025999147" <sip:1112220002QQQ140431267693@devastus01.funbers.net>;tag=as7431db35
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ Call-ID: naIKdyL6kahHCqtpDB9mKwGs3IVssYbq
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ CSeq: 24488 REGISTER
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ Server: Asterisk
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ Supported: replaces, timer
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ Expires: 0
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ Date: Mon, 27 Oct 2014 21:53:26 GMT
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ Content-Length: 0
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ [ 10-27 22:53:23.200  1068: 2014 I/System.out ]
10-27 22:53:23.200    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ --end msg--
10-27 22:53:23.210    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ 22:53:23.214    pjsua_acc.c  ...."12025999147" <sip:1112220002QQQ140431267693@devastus01.funbers.net;transport=tls>: unregistration success
10-27 22:53:23.210    1068-2014/com.funbers.app D/Funbers﹕ notifyRegState: code: 200, reason: OK, expiration: 0
10-27 22:53:23.215    1068-2014/com.funbers.app D/Funbers﹕ Delete account (notifyRegState)
10-27 22:53:23.220    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ 22:53:23.229    pjsua_acc.c  ....Deleting account 0..
10-27 22:53:23.225    1068-2014/com.funbers.app I/System.out﹕ 22:53:23.229    pjsua_acc.c  .....Account id 0 deleted
10-27 22:53:23.225    1068-2014/com.funbers.app A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x24656369 (code=1), thread 2014 (com.funbers.app)
```

Now I wonder, is it even a good idea to unregister/delete account after a call. Or should sip account just be kept alive (and reregister itself every couple of minutes)? Will having sipservice alive in the background drain battery much?

Or could I have missed something in my register/unregister calls. Btw I do unregister by:

```
account.setRegistration(false);
```

Then wait for registration change notification before doing:

```
account.delete();
account = null;
```

Comment: Just a random question. Are you getting the events immediately through GCM or is there a considerable delay? To get push notifications immediately even when phone is in sleep, the phone has to keep a TCP socket alive, which you can do in your app as well.

Comment: Most times it's pretty fast. Fast enough to work for establishing a phone call. But once in a while a gcm push might get delivered with a longer delay.

I have since switched to the new 'VOIP' pushes that apple allows (for ios 8+) - which works even better.

Comment: @RasmusHöglund were you able to find a resolution for this? I'm getting the exact same issue (for outbound and inbound), it appears to be randomly crashing

Comment: @TommyChan Did you ever find a solution to this? Would love to hear it if so.

Comment: @samuelf yes we figured it out..we used an sdk which called into the library and the sdk didn't deallocate one of the objects when destroy is called.

Comment: @TommyChan please can you explain which SDK did you use?

Comment: @RasmusHöglund How to Unregister the SIP Account? using PJSIP

Answer (score 0):

**In my case i delete the call as with making the call simultaneously like :**

> call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);   call.delete();

**Then I use this simply :**

> call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that unregister account is a good idea to do overall after each ended call. I should strongly recommend you to keep account registration alive and battery life does not affect so much actually. I even have a background service in the application which means that when application is destroyed, sip account registration is still alive. In my opinion you should not be worried about phone's battery life, if it's the only reason you want to unregister account after you end the call. If you would like to be able to destroy pjsip and unregister account you maybe could provide a notification from your application to the user which is interactive and from where user can manually be able to unregister. I understand you very well, but to send GCM notifications is not the way you make VOIP applications in Android, it sounds more like a iOS thing. In iPhone you want to send PushKit notifications to wake a VOIP app, but I would never use same approach for Android.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't release the VideoPreview when you hang up call,the crash times  will less than release the VideoPreview.

Comment: I don't think that this call has something with VideoPreview to do, it feels like a regular voice call.